# Selecting First and Last Test in a group of Labtests

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table PatientLab i has a group of tests as below

```
patientid  labtest       dateordered    result
100          cd4         1/1/14          500
100          cd4         1/4/14          200
100          cd4         1/5/15          800
100          vl          1/4/14          564
200          cd4         1/5/16          455
200          cd4         1/6/16          678
200          cd4         1/7/16          234
200          cd4         1/8/16          356
200          vl          1/7/16          1000
```

my desired result;

```
patientid    FirstCD4     FirstCD4Date     LastCD4     LastCD4Date
100          500          1/1/14           800         1/5/15
200          455          1/5/16           356         1/8/16
```

am using postgresql 9

Comment: i have tried `select patientid, dateordered,result
from PatientLab where (patientid) IN (
    select patientid, max(dateordered) AS dateordered
    from PatientLab 
    where labtest = 'cd4' 
    group by patientid
)` am able to only get MAX but am unable to do both max and min from the same table

Comment: Where there is only one CD4 for a Patient, should we still include a row with the details that we have?  Ditto for those with no CD4's?

Comment: @toonice yes but it should have the same date as first and last

Comment: And those with no CD4's?

Comment: @toonice with no CD4's should result an empty result

Comment: In other words, a row with the `patientid` and nothing else or no appearance for that Patient in the results at all?

Comment: @toonice Yes you are right

Comment: Which option from my previous comment, please?

Comment: a row with the patientid and nothing else or no appearance for that Patient in the results at all

Comment: To rephrase my question... Option 1 ) A row with the Patient ID and nothing else, or Option 2) No row at all.  Which option, please?

Comment: Can more than one CD4 be ordered on one day for a patient?  If so, then which value of `result` should we choose?

Comment: @toonice if more than one keep any one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with CTE as
(
select p1.*, 
       row_number() over(partition by patientid order by dateordered asc) as r1, 
       row_number() over(partition by patientid order by dateordered desc) as r2 
from PatientLab p1
where labtest = 'cd4' -- Case sensitive, thanks etsa
)
select C1.PatientID, 
       C1.result as FirstCD4, 
       C1.dateordered as FirstCD4Date, 
       C2.result as LastCD4, 
       C2.dateordered as LastCD4Date
from CTE C1
inner join CTE C2
on C1.PatientID = C2.PatientID
where C1.r1 = 1
and C2.r2 = 1
```

Comment: it is working well in SQL server 2012 but am unable to replicate this in postgresql 9 any idea? @JohnHC

Comment: @Shark-NeilFelyx Window functions and CTEs should both work in Postgres, are you getting any error or just no data?

Comment: I agree with @JohnHC  : it should work in Postgresql too.

Comment: @JohnHC Am not getting any error its just not loading any data in postgresql 9 but loads data in sqlserver 2012. I need it to work in postgres

Comment: you may try this on postgres `create table yourPatient (patientid int, labtest varchar(10), dateordered date, result int);

INSERT INTO yourPatient (patientid , labtest  ,     dateordered  ,  result ) values
 (100     ,'cd4','1/1/14',          500 )
,(100     ,'cd4','1/4/14',          200 )
,(100     ,'cd4','1/5/15',          800 )
,(100     ,'vl ','1/4/14',          564 )
,(200     ,'cd4','1/5/16',          455 )
,(200     ,'cd4','1/6/16',          678 )
,(200     ,'cd4','1/7/16',          234 )
,(200     ,'cd4','1/8/16',          356 )
,(200     ,'vl ','1/7/16',          1000);`

Comment: Postgresql is usually case sensitive regarding WHERE condition (different from MSSQL): try `where labtest = 'cd4' `

Comment: @etsa you saved the day it now working perfect thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can use min and max

```
select a.patientid, min(a.result) as FirstCD4, min(dateordered) as FirstCD4Date
    , max(a.result) as LastCD4, max(dateordered) as LastCD4Date 
    from (
select * from yourpatient where labtest = 'cd4' ) a
group by a.patientid;
```

Your table and details [Code](http://rextester.com/HTF17882)

Comment: The result is not the same as the desired result sometimes the min date can have a max results. Date and results are independent. i.e. it is not a condition that the min date must have the min result